# Preview Multiple Images Before Uploading In mvc (.cshtml)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a File upload control in my mvc project which should preview the selected images and delete if needed before uploading. This Code Works Fine in Normal (.html)view, but it does not render the images when it is added to my mvc project that is in my (.cshtml) view:

```
@{

}

<h2>UploadImage</h2>


<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <style>
        #drop-zone {
            margin-left: 32%;
            margin-top: 15%;
            width: 500px;
            min-height: 150px;
            border: 3px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-family: Arial;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #7E7E7E;
        }

            #drop-zone input {
                position: absolute;
                cursor: pointer;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                opacity: 0;
            }
            /*Important*/

            #drop-zone.mouse-over {
                border: 3px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
                color: #7E7E7E;
            }
        /*If you dont want the button*/

        #clickHere {
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: black;
            font-size: 17px;
            width: 150px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: #F5D56D;
            padding: 10px;
        }

            #clickHere:hover {
                background-color: #FCE085;
            }

        #filename {
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 1.5em;
        }

        .file-preview {
            background: #ccc;
            border: 5px solid #fff;
            box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            display: inline-block;
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }

        .closeBtn:hover {
            color: red;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div id="drop-zone">
            <p>Drop files here...</p>
            <div id="clickHere">
                or click here.. <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple />
            </div>
            <div id="filename">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Upload</button>
        </div>

        }
    </body>
<script>
    var dropZoneId = "drop-zone";
    var buttonId = "clickHere";
    var mouseOverClass = "mouse-over";
    var dropZone = $("#" + dropZoneId);
    var inputFile = dropZone.find("input");
    var finalFiles = {};
    $(function() {



        var ooleft = dropZone.offset().left;
        var ooright = dropZone.outerWidth() + ooleft;
        var ootop = dropZone.offset().top;
        var oobottom = dropZone.outerHeight() + ootop;

        document.getElementById(dropZoneId).addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            dropZone.addClass(mouseOverClass);
            var x = e.pageX;
            var y = e.pageY;

            if (!(x < ooleft || x > ooright || y < ootop || y > oobottom)) {
                inputFile.offset({
                    top: y - 15,
                    left: x - 100
                });
            } else {
                inputFile.offset({
                    top: -400,
                    left: -400
                });
            }

        }, true);

        if (buttonId != "") {
            var clickZone = $("#" + buttonId);

            var oleft = clickZone.offset().left;
            var oright = clickZone.outerWidth() + oleft;
            var otop = clickZone.offset().top;
            var obottom = clickZone.outerHeight() + otop;

            $("#" + buttonId).mousemove(function(e) {
                var x = e.pageX;
                var y = e.pageY;
                if (!(x < oleft || x > oright || y < otop || y > obottom)) {
                    inputFile.offset({
                        top: y - 15,
                        left: x - 160
                    });
                } else {
                    inputFile.offset({
                        top: -400,
                        left: -400
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        document.getElementById(dropZoneId).addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
            $("#" + dropZoneId).removeClass(mouseOverClass);
        }, true);


        inputFile.on('change', function(e) {
            finalFiles = {};
            $('#filename').html("");
            var fileNum = this.files.length,
                initial = 0,
                counter = 0;

            $.each(this.files, function(idx, elm) {
                finalFiles[idx] = elm;

            });

            for (initial; initial < fileNum; initial++) {
                counter = counter + 1;

                $('#filename').append('<div id="file_' + initial + '"> <img src="file:///C:/Users/Ashwanth/Pictures/'+this.files[initial].name+'")/><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-file fa-stack-1x "></i><strong class="fa-stack-1x" style="color:#FFF; font-size:12px; margin-top:2px;">' + counter + '</strong></span>' + this.files[initial].name + '<br><Button   class=" btn btn-primary closeBtn" onclick="removeLine(this)" title="remove">Remove</Button></div>');

            }
        });



    })

    function removeLine(obj) {
        inputFile.val('');
        var jqObj = $(obj);
        var container = jqObj.closest('div');

        var index = container.attr("id").split('_')[1];
        container.remove();

        delete finalFiles[index];
        console.log(finalFiles);
    }
</script>
```

I hope MVC Overwrites the url in my javascript. Any Ideas?